# Data structure to efficiently calculate sum of reachable weights on dynamic directed acyclic graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a directed acyclic graph, where each vertex has a "weight" attribute. The reachable vertices from an initial vertex is the set of all vertices reachable by following one or more edges, starting at the initial vertex. The reachable weight sum is the sum of all weights on reachable vertices from an initial vertex. Additionally, I can add directed edges and vertices to the graph at will, however the graph will always remain acyclic.

Are there any data structures I can augment the graph with that will be useful for efficiently calculating the reachable weight sum from any given initial vertex, and updatable when the graph is updated?

Comment: Interesting problem. I suspect there's no fast way to do this, because if there were then you could assign distinct powers of 2 as weights to represent items in some universe, and use the algorithm to quickly answer a sequence of queries of the form "Assign the union of sets i and j to k" or "Is element i in set j?". Tarjan's disjoint union/find data structure solves this problem in the special case where all sets are disjoint, and it's tricky enough!

Comment: One ray of hope that I see is that, to use such an algorithm/data structure to answer these queries, your weights need as many bits as there are items in your universe, i.e., weights have values exponential in that -- in contrast to disjoint union/find. So the existence of such an algorithm/data structure would not solve a problem strictly more general than the problem disjoint union/find solves.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a node with a link to a reachable node from an initial node, then the reachable weight increments by the weight of the new node.  Otherwise, if the new node is not linked to any reachable nodes, then the reachable weight is unaffected.

So, if you have one initial node that never changes, then it would be worthwhile to store a set of all its reachable nodes.  However, if you want to optimize the updating of reachable weights from any node, then it would not be worthwhile to store th reachable nodes from every node - the storage reuired would be greater than the graph.